# How to insert / upload image (update entity and blocks) in Draft.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I am trying to insert image to Draft.js editor.

Based on my understanding, I need update entity by [`mergeData`](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/docs/Advanced-Topics-Entities.md) and blocks by [`mergeBlockData`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-modifier.html#mergeblockdata). (I am not sure)

Now I am trying to use `mergeBlockData` to insert a block.

> ```
> mergeBlockData(
>   contentState: ContentState,
>   selectionState: SelectionState,
>   blockData: Map<any, any>
> ): ContentState
> ```

Please read comment in the code.

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';

const selection = this.state.editorState.getSelection();
const contentState = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();

console.log(convertToRaw(contentState));  // for example, I have 3 blocks

const blockData = Map({ ov72: {  // here how to generate a random valid key?
  "key": "ov72",
  "text": " ",
  "type": "atomic",
  "depth": 0,
  "inlineStyleRanges": [],
  "entityRanges": [{
    "offset": 0,
    "length": 1,
    "key": 1
  }],
  "data": {}
}});
const newContentState = Modifier.mergeBlockData(contentState, selection, blockData);

console.log(convertToRaw(newContentState));  // here is wrong, still 3 blocks. Also original blocks have no change

const newEditorState = EditorState.push(this.state.editorState, newContentState);
```

Comment: You are merging  blockData why would the size of blocks increase?

Comment: @NanduKalidindi assume `mergeBlockData` is neither replace or add, what is the function of it? And which correct API should I use?

Comment: I am working on a snippet. But I guess you should use `ContentBlock` if you want to add new blocks.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi would u mind adding a demo for how to use `ContentBlock` to add new block in answer? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Took a while to figure out how to insert image.

```
  insertImage = (editorState, base64) => {
    const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity(
      'image',
      'IMMUTABLE',
      { src: base64 },
    );
    const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
    const newEditorState = EditorState.set(
      editorState,
      { currentContent: contentStateWithEntity },
    );
    return AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(newEditorState, entityKey, ' ');
  };
```

Then you can use

```
const base64 = 'aValidBase64String';
const newEditorState = this.insertImage(this.state.editorState, base64);
this.setState({ editorState: newEditorState });
```

For render image, you can use [Draft.js image plugin](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/image).

Live demo: <kbd>[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/50pp3xlv24)</kbd>

The demo inserts a Twitter logo image.

---

If you want to insert a image from local file, you can try to use `FileReader` API to get that base64.

For how to get base64, it is simple, check

Live demo: <kbd>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xupisiraya/2/edit?js,console,output)</kbd>

Now go ahead to put them together, you can upload image from local file!

Comment: Atomic block is not erasable

Comment: Thanks @Hongbo, by the way the string 'image' in createEntity is case sensitive. you need to use IMAGE or it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [draft-js image plugin](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/image), you can achieve this as follows.

Get the base64 of your image as @Hongbo Miao explained.

```
const imagePlugin = createImagePlugin();//initialize image plugin
const base64 = 'aValidBase64String';
const newEditorState = imagePlugin.addImage(this.state.editorState, base64);
this.setState({ editorState: newEditorState });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a new Block then you probably would want to use `ContentBlock` and not `mergeBlockData`.

**ContentBlock**: https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-block.html#content

Please give this snippet a try.

```
import { genKey } from 'draft-js'

addNewBlock(editorState) {
  const text = 'Alpha';
  const block = new ContentBlock({
    key: genKey(),
    type: 'unstyled',
    text,
  });

  const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
  const blockMap = contentState.getBlockMap().set(block.key, block);                   

  return EditorState.push(editorState, contentState.set('blockMap', blockMap));
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate, I just found the solution after checking source code, I will post another answer including updating both entity and blocks to insert a image soon.

Comment: Where is defined the `genKey()` method?

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas It's an imported method from `DraftJS` library. Please check the updated snippet.